# Slow WebClient.DownloadString?

Tags: c#, sharepoint, iis, webclient

I'm working on a web application that runs with ASP.Net 3.5

Somewhere in the application, I'm making calls to an external system. This call consists on downloading a string from a specific url :

```
string targetUrl = BuildMyUrl();
WebClient wc = new WebClient();
string data = wc.DownloadString(targetUrl);
```

This code works quite well with a acceptable response time (under 500ms).

However, in specific cases this response time is over 15 seconds. I can reproduce the behavior, and I can clearly see the long time is on the `DownloadString` call.

*I don't understand why this occurs in my scenario*.

You will say : "Hey, it's the target system that is slow". But I was not able able to reproduce the behavior outside my application (I've build a small console application that isolate the faulting code. Never get any issue).

I don't know where to look now to understand the issue. What can cause a simple download data to be be lengthy ?

FYI: the target system is an authentication service. The target url is of kind :

> http**S**://mysystem/validate?ticket=XXXYYY

Maybe the https protocol is the issue.

Does using WebClient class under IIS can alter the behavior of the WebClient ?

[Edit] I've tried :

- To explicitly set the `Proxy` property of the WebClient object to null
- I've replaced the DownloadData call by this code :

  var req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.CreateDefault(new Uri(targetUrl));
  using (var response = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse())
  {
      using (var sr = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
      {
          data= sr.ReadToEnd();
      }
  }

None of this test were successful.

Comment: does this happen under heavy load conditions ?

Comment: @FelicePollano: no. It occurs on a specific case, I.E. after a signout, then signin again on the authentication system. But only from the consumer web app (not from the test console application).

Comment: The WebClient is really slow. I would normally go for a simple sockets approach but that would be really hard to do for https.

Comment: @CodingBarfield: it works under 250ms for most of my calls which are acceptable. My problem is to understand why in a specific scenario it takes 15seconds. And I hardly see the benefits of rewriting the http protocol. I guess Microsoft's army have better skills than me (and the firepower to unit test every case)

Comment: You only need to write the part of the HTML protocol that you need. Which could be pretty small and pretty simple and pretty fast.
I remember using the webbrowser control for https data and simply load the document html instead of using the webclient.

Comment: 15 seconds sounds like a timeout, but presumably it is not your actual DownloadString that is timing out. Is it possible that it is attempting to check the revocation status on your certificate which I believe times out after 15 seconds if the server is not available?

Comment: it's possible, but I don't know how to validate this theory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The latency was due to a certificate validation timeout. One of the issuer in the chain was not correctly deployed in the client server.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) or some integrated network analyzer inside Chrome/FF browsers to see the HTTPS requests/responses and their headers.